# check if radio button has been select with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

So i have this:

```
<p:selectOneRadio id="gender"  style="display: inline-table">
                    <f:selectItem id="male" itemLabel="Male" itemValue="male"/>
                    <f:selectItem id="female" itemLabel="Female" itemValue="female"/>
</p:selectOneRadio>
```

And I want to see if the user has checked let's say the male option:

```
if($("#male").is(":checked") === true){
    errors.push("gender");
}
```

But this does not work. How can I write the above script in order to checked if the male option has been clicked?

Comment: try adding `$(document).ready(function(){  //your code here   });`  around your JS.

Comment: That is not the problem ..im just looking for a way to refer to the radio buttons

Comment: update your tags and be more specific this is in java, misleading question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set an option to checked by doing:

```
$('input[name=gender]:first').prop('checked', true);
```

You can check if an option is checked with:

```
if($('input[name=gender]:first').is(':checked')) { 
  console.log("option is checked"); 
}
```

Comment: You sure you wrote that corectly?

Comment: Nope, had a typo :)

Comment: So this returns true or false?

Comment: Sorry I didn't read properly that you wanted to check the input, I've updated my answer.